# How to auto increase the number in ACF PRO LOOP

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater, acfpro

I want to auto increase number in each "id", I using ACF PRO and chose type "Repeater".
I tried these code bellow but it doesn't work

````
<?php
$counter = -1;
if( have_rows('thongtin') ):
    while ( have_rows('thongtin') ) : the_row(); $counter++ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/listmatcat'); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
else :
endif;
?> 

// The code in templates/listmatcat.php file
// I want to auto increase the number with #pr_file 

<tr>
    <td class="col col1">
        <p class="name r"><?php the_sub_field('masomatcat') ?></p>
        <a href="#pr_file<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="open_profile" rel="pr_dt"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('anhmatcattrai'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="clearAll"></div>
        <a href="#pr_file<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="open_profile"><span class="active_s"></span></a>
    </td>
    <td class="col_center"></td>
    <td class="col col2" style="text-align:left">
        <div class="info"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('anhmatcatphai'); ?>" alt="" /></div>
    </td>
</tr>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a limitation of the get_template_part() function. According to [this article](https://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/), you would want to do something like this:

```
include(locate_template('[YOUR-FILE-NAME].php'));
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need to be using an external file for the loop's content (if it is only ever used by this one file) just remove the get_template_part() and put the content directly in the loop.